# iOS: Where is file path that [UIImage imageNamed] load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

In my ios project, I have loaded an image to `ImageView` by using:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
```

This image I have in project by using: right click project, add files. And images is added to [Project Name] directory.

But I try to delete this image physically in Finder (move to trash). Clean and Build project and run again, and this image still appear on `ImageView`. I really cannot explain why.

So my question is: the method `[UIImage imageNamed]` where images in xcode project will be searched and loaded ? I see some projects, they put inside `Image` folder and everything still load successfully. And why when I delete those image file, nothing wrong happen ? Does it cache data somewhere else ?

Thanks :)

Comment: In addition to doing a clean build, you must delete the app from your iOS device or simulator since the file is still there.

Comment: try shift + alt + cmd + K. it cleanup your build folder.

Comment: @maddy thanks. I have deleted app on iOS Simulator. and everything as I expected. So, why new rebuild app doesn't override old one (including resources). Thanks :)

Comment: Development builds with Xcode simply copy the latest version of the app onto the device. It doesn't do a proper replacement like you get when updating an app from the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't look for the image with finder - delete it within Xcode.

Yes, the method [UIImage imageNamed] is where the app is searching the bundle for preloaded images.
As a rule of thumb, manage your files, groups, folders... with Xcode, not finder.

Look in your project target build phases wether the file is still "there" as a "copy bundle resource".

Comment: ah. I have checked and as you say :D so. AFAIK, when I add resources (images for example) XCode will save/cache somewhere else ? Because I have deleted on hard drive, so I think XCode cannot touch those resources. thanks :)